# @SneakyThrowsWhen use lombok ”@SneakyThrows“，unsupported class file major version 61

Tags: java, lombok

I am learning to use Lombok in a Maven project. When I use "@SneakyThrows", there are some errors. I found that when I deleted "@SneakyThrows", the errors disappeared.

Here are the errors and code.

```
java: Error during the transformation of 'com.zem.mybatis.DAO.BO.Bus'; post-compiler 'lombok.bytecode.SneakyThrowsRemover' caused an exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 61
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:189)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:170)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:156)
    at lombok.bytecode.AsmUtil.fixJSRInlining(AsmUtil.java:37)
    at lombok.bytecode.SneakyThrowsRemover.applyTransformations(SneakyThrowsRemover.java:46)
    at lombok.core.PostCompiler.applyTransformations(PostCompiler.java:43)
    at lombok.core.PostCompiler$1.close(PostCompiler.java:77)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.ClassWriter.writeClass(ClassWriter.java:1508)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.genCode(JavaCompiler.java:738)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.generate(JavaCompiler.java:1617)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.generate(JavaCompiler.java:1585)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:946)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.lambda$doCall$0(JavacTaskImpl.java:104)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.invocationHelper(JavacTaskImpl.java:152)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.doCall(JavacTaskImpl.java:100)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call(JavacTaskImpl.java:94)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.javac.JavacMain.compile(JavacMain.java:238)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.java.JavaBuilder.lambda$compileJava$2(JavaBuilder.java:518)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.java.JavaBuilder.invokeJavac(JavaBuilder.java:564)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.java.JavaBuilder.compileJava(JavaBuilder.java:516)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.java.JavaBuilder.compile(JavaBuilder.java:359)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.java.JavaBuilder.doBuild(JavaBuilder.java:284)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.java.JavaBuilder.build(JavaBuilder.java:238)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runModuleLevelBuilders(IncProjectBuilder.java:1507)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuildersForChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:1141)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildTargetsChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:1288)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunkIfAffected(IncProjectBuilder.java:1106)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunks(IncProjectBuilder.java:877)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuild(IncProjectBuilder.java:459)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.build(IncProjectBuilder.java:197)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.runBuild(BuildRunner.java:131)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:334)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:162)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler.lambda$channelRead0$0(BuildMain.java:218)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
```

```java
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@Builder
public class Bus {
    private @Singular("a")
    List<Integer> arrayList;
    @Getter(lazy = true) private final static Bus bus = Bus.builder().a(1).build();
}
```

This is the dependency of Lombok.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <version>1.18.16</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: The error means that you're using a version of Lombok (or actually, of ASM) that doesn't support Java 17. This suggest you are using a Lombok version *before* 1.18.22. Which version of Lombok are you using?

Comment: So, you are using Lombok version 1.18.16. You need to upgrade this to 1.18.22 or newer.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Question has been resolved when I changed my lombok denpendency from version from 1.18.16 to 1.18.24.Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 7):

You're using Lombok 1.18.16, but Lombok added Java 17 support in version 1.18.22 (see [its changelog](https://projectlombok.org/changelog), or [issue 2898](https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok/issues/2898)). You need to update to 1.18.22 or higher to make it work on Java 17.